# shifting array items up

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to rearrange data given to me in an array so that it is more manageable

here is the array given

```
$config = array(
     "themes" => array(
         "0" => array(
                 "Name" => 'connect',
                 "Description" => 'Connect your song to the previous song by reusing a word in the artist or title.'
             ),

         "1" => array(
                 "Name" => 'color',
                 "Description" => 'Play songs with a color in the artist name or song title, the song could also have something to do with color.'
             )
     )
);
```

here is the desired output

```
$desired_config = array(
     "themes" => array(
         "connect" => array(
                 "0" => 'Connect your song to the previous song by reusing a word in the artist or title.'
             ),

         "color" => array(
                 "0" => 'Play songs with a color in the artist name or song title, the song could also have something to do with color.'
             )
     )
);
```

and here is what what i tried

```
foreach($config as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){

        foreach($value as $index=>$object){
            if(is_array($object)){
                foreach($object as $command){
                $config[$key][$command['Name']][] = $command['Description'];

                }   
            }else{
                $config[$key] = $value;
            }

        }
    }
}
print_r($config);
```

and my very poor results

```
Array
(
[themes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Name] => connect
                [Description] => Connect your song to the previous song by reusing a word in the artist or title.
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Name] => color
                [Description] => Play songs with a color in the artist name or song title, the song could also have something to do with color.
            )

        [c] => Array
            (
                [0] => c
                [1] => c
            )

        [C] => Array
            (
                [0] => C
            )

        [P] => Array
            (
                [0] => P
            )

    )
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/fXwbMHwM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_config = array();
foreach ($config as $key=>$item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        $new_config[$key] = array();
        foreach($item as $value) {
            if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('Name', $value) && array_key_exists('Description', $value)) {
                $new_config[$key][$value['Name']] = array($value['Description']);   
            } else {
                $new_config[$key][] = $value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $new_config[$key] = $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$desired_config = array();
foreach($config["themes"] as $index => $item) {
    $desired_config["themes"][$item["Name"]] = array($item["Description"]);
}

print_r($desired_config);
```

Comment: @mcgrailm i think you have got the answer from Nadh

Comment: this would overwrite with a new array every time an item['name'] was the same rather than adding it to an array

Comment: but i think i can get what I need from this

Answer (score 1):

I think this function will do what you need:

```
function shiftMyArray($myArray) {
$ret = array();
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
    if (is_array($value)){
        $newArray = array();
        foreach ($value as $index => $object){
            if (is_array($object)){
                $newArray[$object['Name']] = $object;
                unset($newArray[$object['Name']]['Name']);
            } else {
                $newArray[$index] = $object;
            }
        }
        $ret[$key] = $newArray;
    } else {
        $ret[$key] = $value;
    }
}
return $ret;
}
var_dump($config, shiftMyArray($config));
```

Comment: this returns the description int the array but gets me closer to home instead of description it should be an array item as there can be multiple items in whatever the "theme" maybe